# Showing an alert message before a RedirectionToAction

Tags: redirect, model-view-controller

I have an MVC app and the users can send inquiries. After an inquire is submitted if there are no errors the app redirects the user to a proper page. I am trying to have a message showing before the new page opens.
here is the controller code:

```
if(Session["login"] == null)
{
 string retsnd = clgnrhlp.SendEnquiry(name, email, message);
 ViewBag.MSGSENT = retsnd;
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
}
else
{
 string retsnd = clgnrhlp.SendEnquiry(name, email, message);
 ViewBag.MSGSENT = retsnd;
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Trades");
}
```

in my View(Contact.cshtml) I tried this:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
  var dataexists = @ViewBag.MSGSENT;
  if (dataexists)
    Response.Write(@ViewBag.MSGSEN)
</script>
```

but nothing happens, it goes straight to the other page.
Any clues, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the issue described in my question. I decided to use TempData instead of a ViewBag. So the TempData holds the value I want to show in the message. By the code, I am redirecting the user for different pages if it is logged in or not but the message will be the same.
So in the two Views where the user will be redirected I place this code:

```
@if (TempData["sent"] != null)
 {
   <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("@(TempData["sent"])");
   </script>
 }
```

and it worked ok.

Still, if any of you guys have a better way to do that I am open to suggestions.
Thanks